# Kafka producer authentication within a databricks notebook

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am looking for a method to authenticate my databricks notebook to publish messages to a kafka topic which requires an IMS token for auth while using the spark kafka library to publish.

Does anyone have any idea how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

I was trying the following command -:

```
df.write.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
.option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
.option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", EH_SASL)
.option("kafka.batch.size", 250)
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "server1:port1,server2:port2,server3:port3")
.option("kafka.request.timeout.ms", 120000)
.option("topic", "topic_name")
.save()
```

I get the error if I don't pass any auth properties-:

*org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (executor 0): kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic topic_name not present in metadata after 60000 ms.*

But unable to find the correct EH_SASL format which comprises the clickt_id and IMS token for auth.

Comment: I don't think we can answer this without knowing what SASL module is enabled on the brokers themselves. Do you have documentation about how to use other Java based Kafka clients?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if there is a need to add kafka.sasl.jaas.config with username and password.
"kafka.sasl.jaas.config": 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="{kafka_username}" password="{kafka_pwd}

Comment: I don't have a username and password for authentication, I have an access token, ClientID, and a secret_key only. for that couldn't find a proper kafka.sasl.jaas.config format